# How should I rewrite code in order to create two child processes each of which execs childtest.c from parent process

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, child-process

I want to rewrite forkexetest.c to create two child processes, each of which execs childtest.

However, do not have more than three child processes.

How should I rewrite it.

forkexetext.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wait.h>
int main(void){
 int pid, cpid;
 int status;
 int i;
 pid = fork();
 if(pid == -1){ 
 perror("fork error");
 exit(-1);
 }
 if(pid == 0){ 
 execl("childtest", "childtest", (char *)NULL);
 perror("exec error");
 exit(-1);
 }else{ 
 printf("[parent] process pid=%d...\n",getpid());
 for(i=0; i<5; i++){ 
 printf("[parent] %d\n",i);
 sleep(1);
}
 cpid = wait(&status); 
 if(cpid == -1){
 perror("wait error");
 exit(-1);
 }
 printf("[parent] child process(%d) status %d\n", cpid, status>>8);
 printf("[parent] process finished\n");
 }
 return 0;
```

childtest.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void){
 int i;
 printf("[child] process id=%d...\n",getpid());
 for(i=0; i<5; i++){ 
 printf("[child] %d\n",i);
 sleep(2);
 }
 return 123;
}
```

Comment: You need to write a second `fork()` and `exec*()` sequence.  I'd create a function to do the job and call it twice.  You can decide where to put a `wait()` loop to collect dead child processes — it could be in the 'run a child program' function, or it could be at the top level in `main()`.  It depends in part on whether the children are required to run concurrently or whether sequential execution is OK.  Waiting for children in the 'run a child' function forces sequential execution.  Putting the loop in the `main()` function after the children have been launched allows concurrent execution.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could suggest me a sample code.

Comment: Were it up to me, the child process would print the PID on every line of output.  It's a good idea to tag outputs with the process that generates them when working on multi-process exercises.  It simplifies the debugging, all else apart.

Answer (score 0):

Code that lets the children execute concurrently:

```
/* SO 73016452 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static void fork_childtest(void)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        execl("childtest", "childtest", (char *)NULL);
        perror("exec error");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    fork_childtest();
    fork_childtest();

    printf("[parent %d]\n", getpid());
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("[parent %d] loop %d\n", getpid(), i);
        sleep(1);
    }

    int status;
    int corpse;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        printf("[parent %d] Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", getpid(), corpse, status);
    }

    printf("[parent %d] process finished\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the standard header is `<sys/wait.h>` not `<wait.h>`.

Modified child code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    printf("[child] process id=%d...\n", getpid());
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("[child %d] %d\n", getpid(), i);
        sleep(2);
    }
    return 123;
}
```

#### Example output

```
[parent 13076]
[parent 13076] loop 0
[child] process id=13079...
[child 13079] 0
[child] process id=13080...
[child 13080] 0
[parent 13076] loop 1
[parent 13076] loop 2
[child 13080] 1
[child 13079] 1
[parent 13076] loop 3
[parent 13076] loop 4
[child 13080] 2
[child 13079] 2
[child 13079] 3
[child 13080] 3
[child 13079] 4
[child 13080] 4
[parent 13076] Child 13080 exited with status 0x7B00
[parent 13076] Child 13079 exited with status 0x7B00
[parent 13076] process finished
```